# Check out form to calculate total cost of items

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making an ecommerce style website where people can purchase smartphones. In this website I have a checkout form where users can select what phone they wish to choose and then depending on the quantity the form displays the total cost for the user. However since I am using drop down options I am not sure on how to go about getting the value of the phone, multiplying it by the quantity and displaying the total cost at the bottom.

```
div class="contact-wrap">
  <div class="title-box">
  <b>Check Out</b>
  </div>

  <div id="form1">

  <img id="phone" src="iphone6.jpg" width="294" height="320"/>
  <select id="phoneList">
    <option value="iphone1.jpg">Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (2019) 512GB Silver</option>
    <option value="iphone2.jpg">Apple iPhone 11 (2019) 128GB Black</option>
    <option value="iphone3.jpg">Apple iPhone 11 (2019) 256GB White</option>
  </select>

  <select id="quantity">
    <p>Quantity</p>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <div id="form2">
  <form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <p>First name: </p><input type="text" name="fname">
  <p>Last name: </p><input type="text" name="lname">
  <p>Email address: </p><textarea id="email" rows = "1" cols = "40" name="email"></textarea>
  <p>Shipping address </p><textarea id="shipping" rows = "6" cols = "40" name="shipping"></textarea><br>
  <input style="float:bottom; margin-top:20px" type="submit" value="Order">
  </form>
  </div>

  </div>
  <script>
      function setPhone() {
    var img = document.getElementById("phone");
    img.src = this.value;
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("phoneList").onchange = setPhone;

      function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
  var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var shipping = document.forms["myForm"]["shipping"].value;

  if (x == "") {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  else if (y == "") {
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  else if (parseInt("0"+x, 10) > 0 || parseInt("0"+y, 10) > 0){
    alert("Numbers not permissable for name");
    return false;
  }
  else if (email == "") {
    alert("Email must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  else if (shipping == "") {
    alert("Shipping address must be filled out");
    return false;
  }

}
  </script>
```

Comment: why you store a pic name in the dropdown value attribute?

Comment: To display a picture of the phone which the user selects from the options

Comment: guess you are using some sort of plugin to do so. You should put the price in the value attribute or use a data-* attribute. Then you can retrieve the attribute for the selected attribute and do the math (note that you have to convert to integer from strings before

Answer (score 0):

Doing some slight edits of your select to include attributes so it looks as follows:

```
<select id="phoneList">
    <option value="iphone1.jpg" data-cost="100">Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max (2019) 512GB Silver</option>
    <option value="iphone2.jpg" data-cost="200">Apple iPhone 11 (2019) 128GB Black</option>
    <option value="iphone3.jpg" data-cost="300">Apple iPhone 11 (2019) 256GB White</option>
</select>
```

Then by getting the selected index and the data-cost defined above using

```
var i = phoneList.selectedIndex;
var phoneCost = document.getElementById("phoneList").getElementsByTagName("option")[i].getAttribute("data-cost");
```

you can get the cost of the selected phone.

Then just multiply the cost of the phone by the quantity from

```
document.getElementById("quantity").value;
```

and display it somewhere on your page.

So when the user selects an option in the dropdown call a function along the lines of

```
<script>
function CalcCosts() {
    //Get user selected items
    var i = phoneList.selectedIndex;
    var phonecost = document.getElementById("phoneList").getElementsByTagName("option")[i].getAttribute("data-cost");
    var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);

    //Display on page
    document.getElementById("PLACETODISPLAY").innerHTML = phonecost * quantity;
}
</script>
```

You could call the function using the onclick of the dropdowns as follows

```
<select id="quantity" onclick="CalcCosts()">
    <p>Quantity</p>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Edit:
Include suggestions from comments.

Comment: this require to hardcode in the code the price of each. Better to use some additional attribute (data-) for the option to handle the price. So you can build the option from, say, a database or any other source and you can easily manage when prices change

Comment: @LelioFaieta I don't think based on the code above hardcoding is an issue. However, I agree your solution is cleaner and have edited accordingly :)